# App for advance Sound editing (Alternative to Cool Edit Pro)

Tags: 11.10, sound-editor

Looking for an alternative to Cool Edit Pro which is a sound editing software for Windows that can do a lot for sound. Any tool in Ubuntu that helps me edit sound, channels, etc.. as close or advance as Cool Edit Pro is or similar programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)**

> You can use Audacity to:
>
> - Record live audio.
> - Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
> - Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
> - Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
> - Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
> - And more! See the complete [list of features](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features)

Install

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

[Tutorial](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Category:Tutorial)

[image]

Comment: I thought that was for Windows. I think I read somewhere about this tool but I swear it was for windows. Thanks Achu. It did exactly what I wanted with some sound files.